# Generate Prefix Number ID with Condition By Group ID

Tags: mysql, concatenation, zerofill

First this is my table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `group` (
    `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `member` (
    `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `group_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `code` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    KEY `group_id` (`group_id`),
    FOREIGN KEY (`group_id`) REFERENCES `group` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I need `member.id` look like 001, 002, 003. . i following `lpad(id, 3, 0)` and case close

But how to reset 001, 002, 003 back to 001 again where have different `group_id`

This query have result 01-001, 01-002, 02-003, 03-004 (`group.id` - `member.id`)

```
SELECT CONCAT(lpad(g.id, 2, 0),'-',lpad(m.id, 3, 0)) AS id, m.name
FROM member m
LEFT JOIN group g ON g.id = m.group_id
ORDER BY m.id ASC
```

Please help, i need 01-001, 01-002, 02-001, 03-001 (`group.id` - `member.id`)

Or can i use trigger to make my `member.code` auto generate when insert to 01-001, 01-002, 02-003, 03-004 base on `group.id` - `member.id`